# SCSS Variable Name Interpolation

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to create a bunch of buttons using a loop and a map in SCSS, but I don't know if the following is possible. I couldn't find a direct answer when I searched for this.

Does anyone know if I can do this? And if I can, what in my syntax is wrong?

```
  $button-variants:(
  primary: 'primary',
  secondary: 'secondary',
  positive: 'positive',
  negative: 'negative',
  warning: 'warning'
  );

  @each $key,$val in $button-variants {
    .c-button--#{$key} {
       @include button($color-#{$key}, $color-#{$key}-highlight, true);
    }
  }
```

I'm receiving an error:

```
Error: Undefined variable: "$color-".
        on line 54 of source/css/scss/04-components/_button.scss
>>        @include button($color-#{$key}, $color-#{$key}-highlight, true);
```

Comment: checkout http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/SASS-interpolation-in-a-name-of-variable-nest-variables-within-variables

Comment: Where are you defining `$color`? Looks like that should be interpolated as `#{$color}` regardless

Answer (score 0):

Try something analogous to this:

```
/* Define the Sassy Map called $icons */
$icons: (
  checkmark: a,
  plus: b,
  minus: c
);

/* For each key in the map, create a class */
@each $name, $value in $icons {
  .icon--#{$name} {
    content: $value;
  }
}
```

And you'll get the following result:

```
/* For each key in the map, created a class */
.icon--checkmark {
  content: "a";
}

.icon--plus {
  content: "b";
}

.icon--minus {
  content: "c";
}
```